# Какой командой mc распаковывает *.rar?

Tags: linux, xubuntu, rar

Скачан архив **fias_dbf.rar**, думаю многим знаком. Пытался распаковать его немыслимым числом иструментов, ничто не может с ним справиться - бился полтора часа. В итоге зашел внутрь архива через mc и скопировал содержимое наружу. Вопрос: как выглядит консольная команда вышеописанного действия?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно скачать

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

а потом перейти в директорию с архивом и

```
unrar e fias_dbf.rar
```

[unrar - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unrar)